# FreeConsole then AttachConsole not working

Tags: c++, windows, console-application

I'm working with a C++ Console Application in Visual Studio 2013, working on Windows.

First I detached the console using FreeConsole, it works; then, I tried to attach it back using AttachConsole, but nothing happened --

```
#include <psapi.h>

DWORD winpid = GetCurrentProcessId(); // get pid
std::cout << winpid; // it works    
FreeConsole(); // console lost
std::cout << "Lost to the bit bucket"; //nothing happen, as expected
AttachConsole(winpid); // try find the console back....
std::cout << "c"; // ... but failed
```

How could I find the lost Console back?

Comment: You should start by checking what [`AttachConsole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952(v=vs.85).aspx) returns. And if it fails then you should get the error code to find out why.

Comment: Well, you can of course not attach to a console that no longer exists.  You'd have to use AllocConsole() instead and re-initialize the streams so they work with the new console.

Comment: @HansPassant thx for the suggestion, now i have another error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059902/attachconsole-error-5-access-is-denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you called FreeConsole(), your console ceases to exist.  You cannot call AttachConsole() because there is nothing to attach to.  You should instead use AllocConsole() to create a new console and then "attach" to it like so:

```c++
AllocConsole();
FILE* f;
freopen_s(&f, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
```

Then to free the console later on:

```c++
fclose(f);
FreeConsole();
```