# AttachConsole Error 5: Access is denied

Tags: c++, windows, console-application

I'm working with a C++ Console Application in Visual Studio 2013, working on Windows.

First I detached the console using `FreeConsole`, it works; then, called `AllocConsole` as [FreeConsole then AttachConsole not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059618/freeconsole-then-attachconsole-not-working) suggested, returns `true` meaning success; last, I tried to attach it back using `AttachConsole`, but nothing happened --

```
#include <psapi.h>

DWORD winpid = GetCurrentProcessId(); // get pid
std::cout << winpid; // it works    
FreeConsole(); // console lost
bool succeed = AllocConsole(); //succeeded.
succeed = AttachConsole(winpid); // return false: failed.
if (!succeed)
    LastError = GetLastError(); // Error Code 5
```

[System Error Code 5 means](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
5 (0x5)
Access is denied.
```

How shall I attach the console properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the AllocConsole call before AttachConsole.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952(v=vs.85).aspx):
A process can be attached to at most one console. If the calling process is already attached to a console, the error code returned is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (5).

Comment: What you suggested is exactly what I did before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059618/freeconsole-then-attachconsole-not-working , it doesn't work.

Comment: so did you check the result of FreeConsole?

Comment: FreeConsole returns true, meaning successful, as the previous post explained.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here. Reattach to a destroyed console? You either recreated one or don't destroy a previous one.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i'm trying, recreate one by `bool succeed = AllocConsole(); //succeeded.`, but failed in attaching by `AttachConsole(winpid);`.

Comment: after AllocConsole your process already has the new one attached (no need to AttachConsole), so ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED is expected.

Comment: Now I realized the problem: `     
 FreeConsole(); 
 /* std::cout << "invisible"; */
 AllocConsole(); 
 std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
` if the line of "invisible" is commented out, "hi" could be seen; however if that line is uncommented, "hi" won't appear. But this is another problem. Definitely your solution works. Thank you!